# Using Next inside a Turborepo error with warning and ELIFECYCLE error, how to fix?

Tags: node.js, next.js, pnpm, turborepo

Inside a project using [Turbo](https://turbo.build/) and managed with `pnpm`, a new Next.js app was created. Launching the app works fine, however terminating it prints warnings and errors.

Why, and how to fix these?

```bash
% pnpm dev --filter=@dyn-app/web-hello

> dyn@ dev /path/to/project
> turbo dev "--filter=@dyn-app/web-hello"

• Packages in scope: @dyn-app/web-hello
• Running dev in 1 packages
• Remote caching disabled
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: cache bypass, force executing 88fcaa915ac0ca2a
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: 
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: > @dyn-app/web-hello@0.1.0 dev /path/to/project/apps/web-hello
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: > pnpm with-env:dev next dev -- -p 3700
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: 
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: 
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: > @dyn-app/web-hello@0.1.0 with-env:dev /path/to/project/apps/web-hello
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: > dotenv -e .env.development.local "next" "dev" "--" "-p" "3700"
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: 
^C@dyn-app/web-hello:dev:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev:  WARN   Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev: 

@dyn-app/web-hello:dev:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.                                                                                                                                                                          
@dyn-app/web-hello:dev:  WARN   Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Again, all dependencies are installed with `pnpm` inside a monorepo; the `node_modules` is not within the project, and the project launches just fine.

---

#### Update

After reviewing `pnpm` code, I have created two tickets:

- https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/7164
- https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/7165